# SQL Server Creating Indexes Catalogs with joined tables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

So at the moment I am building a Advanced Search in .NET, and getting the results is just proving a bit slow so was looking at creating indexes on the tables.

I.e went to tables and define full text index.

So now I have my catalog with the 5 tables and selected columns.

But I cant see how this catalog actually joins these tables ?

I.e. in my "slow" stored procedure I could have

```
select * 
from table1 
inner join table2 ON table1.id = table2.linkedID
```

etc for other tables ?

and now I guess I can go

```
select * from catalogName
```

but how does `catalogName` know what columns to join for the inner join etc

Answer (score 0):

You don't query the fultext catalog directly, you use the fulltext functions in your query, like [`CONTAINS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx), [`CONTAINSTABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx), [`FREETEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx) and [`FREETEXTTABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx):

```
SELECT field, field, field
FROM table
WHERE CONTAINS(field, 'some text');
```

Full text has nothing to do with joining tables and if your query is slow because you join 5 tables then FT is unlikely to help at all.